# Does the 'access_token' get from Gitlab Oauth2 work same to the one manually created in the profile setting?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, gitlab

I used both methods to get or create 'access_token', the one manually created works fine. I can using this one though Gitlab Wiki Api to retrieve the content from specific project's wiki pages.

However, when I used the 'access_token' returned from Gitlab Oauth2 method, the same Gitlab Wiki Api returned `status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized"`

So are the two 'access_token' same thing, or how to make them work in the same way?

Thanks,
CZ

Answer (score 0):

After digging in Gitlab's issue tracker, I found this as the answer.

Theoretically, these two 'access_token' should be the same things. However, so far, they are not compatible yet. The manually assigned is called PAT (personal access token), https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#personal-access-tokens; while the Oauth2 returned is bearer tokens which are authenticated by using the  gem and uses its own database table.

Details are here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/63438